# csv file codification affects salesforce's Dataloader 25.0.2 behavior?

Tags: upload, salesforce

I've been trying to upsert and delete some data at objects in salesforce cloud using Data Loader 25.0.2. Data Loader executes without problems, but the insertions/deletions don't get done. The log file returns some lines with this errors:

> 2012-10-03 17:13:16,958 ERROR [deleteAccount]
>   client.PartnerClient processResult (PartnerClient.java:432) - Errors
>   were found on item0 2012-10-03 17:13:16,958 ERROR
>   [deleteAccount] client.PartnerClient processResult
>   (PartnerClient.java:434) - Error code is:INVALID_ID_FIELD 2012-10-03
>
> 17:13:16,958 ERROR [deleteAccount] client.PartnerClient
>   processResult (PartnerClient.java:435) - Error message:invalid record
>   id

I've checked that the object ids match, so there are not obvious differences between the data at the cloud and the csv being used to the deletion command.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that the codification of the .csv file I've uploaded differed from the codification used for internal representation in salesforce for the data of that object. For example: My .csv file was codified on ANSI instead of UTF-8. This detail got salesforce into confussion. So I had only to change the file's codification to UTF-8 and everything got solved.